# Scaning multiple json files and merging all data (not duplicate) into a .csv file in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, timestamp

I'm trying to go over multiple json files, appending them into a big list, and then at the end scan the big list, adding each (unique) data entry into a CSV file but can't figure out how to do it.

Oh, and another issue I'm having is that I want each JSON file which has the namestructure with a timestamp they were created like this *"AJSONFILE_2023-11-21_11-18-21.json"*. Each timestamp I want to be a unique column in the CSV file I create at the end.

The content of the JSON files look like this:

```
{
  "apps": {
    "module_a": {
      "state": "Starting",
      "restart counter": 0
    },
    "module_b": {
      "state": "Starting",
      "restart counter": 1
    }
  }
}
```

My code currently looks like this:

```
import csv
import json
import os
import re


def scan_caps_files() -> None:
    json_files_directory = "FILE_DIRECTORY"

    all_data = []
    timestamp_pattern = re.compile(r"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}")
    filetime = None
    extracted_timestamps = []
    extracted_info = []

    extracted_info.append({"Name": "Name", "Timestamp": "-", "Restart Counter": "Restart Counter"})

    result = list()

    for filename in os.listdir(json_files_directory):
        if filename.endswith(".json"):
            file_path = os.path.join(json_files_directory, filename)
            filetime = timestamp_pattern.search(filename)

            try:
                with open(file_path, "r") as file:
                    json_content = json.load(file)
                    all_data.append(json_content)
                    extracted_timestamps.append(filetime.group())
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error while reading file {file_path}: {e}")

    with open('all_crashes.json', 'w') as output_file:
        json.dump(result, output_file)
        print("Path to newly created JSON file:", os.path.abspath("all_crashes.json"))

    try:
        for data in all_data:
            crash_data = data.get("apps", {})

            for app_name, app_data in crash_data.items():
                new_info = {"Name": "", "Timestamp": "", "Restart Counter": 0}

                new_info["Name"] = app_name
                new_info["Timestamp"] = app_data.get("state", "N/A")
                new_info["Restart Counter"] = app_data.get("restart counter", 0)

                result.extend(new_info)
                print(result)
                if app_name not in extracted_info:
                    extracted_info.append(new_info)
                else:
                    print("Already in the list")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred when trying to scan the file(s): {e}")

    csv_file_path = "output.csv"
    csv_header = ["Name", "Timestamp", "Restart Counter"]

    with open(csv_file_path, mode="w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=csv_header)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(extracted_info)

    print("Absolute Path for CSV File:", os.path.abspath(csv_file_path))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    scan_caps_files()
```

But the printout I get when I use "csvlook output.csv" comes out like this:

```
**| Name                      | Timestamp  | Restart Counter |
| --------------------------- | ---------- | --------------- |
| Name                        | -          | Restart Counter |
| module_a                    | Starting   | 0               |
| module_b                    | Starting   | 1               |
| module_a                    | Running    | 0               |
| module_b                    | Terminated | 1               |**
```

Currently I'm only using two JSON files (for testing purposes to get this done), named "*AJSONFILE_2023-11-21_11-18-21.json*" and "*AJSONFILE_2023-11-21_11-19-23.json*".

Question or more what I want:
I want it to look more like **without duplicated** module names and also a **unique column for each file/timestamp**, plus to **add up all the "restart_counter"** data at the end of the CSV-file looking something like this:

```
**| Name                      | 2023-11-21_11-18-21 | 2023-11-21_11-19-24 | Restart Counter |
| --------------------------- | ------------------- | ------------------- | --------------- |
| module_a                    | Starting            | Running             | 0               |
| module_b                    | Starting            | Terminated          | 2               |**
```

If someone could give me some pointers on where I'm going wrong that would be much appreciated!

I tried to Google, looked here in Stackoverflow, used ChatGPT.

Comment: Hi . Will you please edit your question and add an example of the second JSON that will give the desired output. I imagine it looks something like `...{module_a: {running, 0}, {module_b: {terminated, 1}...`.

Comment: Also, will every module be in every file, or will one file contain modules a and b, while another file contains modules a, b, and c, while another file might only have module c?

Comment: Hi @ZachYoung ! I see you already given me a good answer on what I want - thanks! ^^ the second (or compiled) JSON file should have the look as that of what I gave as my "desired output" for the CSV file. I'm quite new to programming so I can't really say exactly how that JSON file would be structured. But in regards to your second question, to my knowledge all the JSON file will have the same modules. It could of course be cases where some is added or even removed, but will that make a big difference to the logic you've given?

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach this by reading all the JSON files and building up and intermediate data structure that can then be turned into the final CSV.

I mocked up these three input JSONs, adding a module_c, and also making it so not every module appears in every file:

- input_2023-11-21_11-18-21.json:

  ```json
  {
    "apps": {
        "module_a": {"state": "Starting", "restart counter": 0},
        "module_b": {"state": "Starting", "restart counter": 1},
        "module_c": {"state": "Starting", "restart counter": 1}
    }
  }
  ```
- input_2023-11-21_11-19-24.json:

  ```json
  {
    "apps": {
      "module_a": {"state": "Running", "restart counter": 0},
      "module_b": {"state": "Terminated", "restart counter": 1}
    }
  }
  ```
- input_2023-11-21_11-20-07.json:

  ```json
  {
    "apps": {
      "module_c": {"state": "Running", "restart counter": 0}
    }
  }
  ```

The intermediate data structure needs to accumulate the restarts, and pair-up time stamps with states.  For those sample files above, I picture the structure looking like this:

```py
data = {
    "module_a": {
        "Restart Counter": 0,
        "2023-11-21_11-18-21": "Starting",
        "2023-11-21_11-19-24": "Running",
    },
    "module_b": {
        "Restart Counter": 2,
        "2023-11-21_11-18-21": "Starting",
        "2023-11-21_11-19-24": "Terminated",
    },
    "module_c": {
        "Restart Counter": 1,
        "2023-11-21_11-18-21": "Starting",
        "2023-11-21_11-20-07": "Running",
    },
}
```

You can build that structure like:

```py
data = {}
for fname in sorted(glob.glob("*.json")):
    # ':-5' to chomp '.json', '-19:' to take just the date-time stamp
    dt_stamp = fname[:-5][-19:]

    with open(fname) as f:
        for module_name, values in json.load(f)["apps"].items():
            module = data.get(module_name, {"Restart Counter": 0})

            module["Restart Counter"] += values["restart counter"]
            module[dt_stamp] = values["state"]

            data[module_name] = module
```

You can use the csv module's DictWriter to turn that structure (with just a little work) into the final CSV.

The DictWriter requires you to tell it what fieldnames to expect in the dicts it tries to row-ify, you also control the order of those fieldnames:

```py
timestamps = set()
for values in data.values():
    for x in values:
        if x != "Restart Counter":
            timestamps.add(x)
final_fieldnames = ["Name"] + sorted(timestamps) + ["Restart Counter"]
```

Create the DictWriter with those fieldnames, then loop over the items in data.  You'll need to take the key (the module name) and values and combine them into a single dict, `{"Name": module_name, **values}`, to pass to the DictWriter's writerow() method:

```py
with open("output.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=final_fieldnames, )
    writer.writeheader()
    for module_name, values in sorted(data.items()):
        writer.writerow({"Name": module_name, **values})
```

```
| Name     | 2023-11-21_11-18-21 | 2023-11-21_11-19-24 | 2023-11-21_11-20-07 | Restart Counter |
|----------|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|-----------------|
| module_c | Starting            |                     | Running             | 1               |
| module_b | Starting            | Terminated          |                     | 2               |
| module_a | Starting            | Running             |                     | 0               |
```

The DictWriter handled the cases when a row didn't have all the fieldnames by just writing an empty string, you can change this by setting the `restval=` property:

```py
...
writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=final_fieldnames, restval="FOO-BAR")
...
```

```
| Name     | 2023-11-21_11-18-21 | 2023-11-21_11-19-24 | 2023-11-21_11-20-07 | Restart Counter |
|----------|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|-----------------|
| module_a | Starting            | Running             | FOO-BAR             | 0               |
| module_b | Starting            | Terminated          | FOO-BAR             | 2               |
| module_c | Starting            | FOO-BAR             | Running             | 1               |
```